# Does this product of Gaussian distributions have an analytic marginal?

Tags: integration, bayesian

I have a conditional: $p(x|a,d,q) = \mathcal{N}(x|d/(1-a),q/(1-a^2))$, where $\mathcal{N}(t|u,v)$ denotes a normally distributed variable $t$ with mean $u$ and variance $v$.

I have a prior over $a$ and $d$: $p(a,d|\mu_a,\mu_d,\sigma^2_a,\sigma^2_d)$, which is a bivariate normal distribution $\mathcal{N}([a \ d]^\intercal|[\mu_a \ \mu_d]^\intercal,diag(\sigma^2_a,\sigma^2_d))$ that is truncated at 0 and 1 for $a$ but unbounded for $d$.

All variables ($x, a, d, q, \mu_a, \mu_d, \sigma^2_a, \sigma^2_d$) are scalars, $^\intercal$ denotes a transpose and $diag$ denotes a diagonal covariance matrix.

I want to integrate out the unknown $a$ and $d$ from the joint $p(x|a,d,q)p(a,d|\mu_a,\mu_d,\sigma^2_a,\sigma^2_d)  = p(x,a,d||q,\mu_a,\mu_d,\sigma^2_a,\sigma^2_d)$ to obtain the marginal $p(x|q,\mu_a,\mu_d,\sigma^2_a,\sigma^2_d)$.

I note that the mean of $p(x|a,d,q)$ is **not a linear function** of $[a \ d]^\intercal$ and **the variance of $p(x|a,d,q)$ depends on $a$**. Both these properties violate the standard linear Gaussian model that I am familiar with. Does this marginal have an analytical solution? Is the desired marginal even still a Gaussian? Can anybody tell me what it is, or point me to a derivation for this type of marginal?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does  $x|d/(1-a)$ mean in $ \mathcal{N}(x|d/(1-a),q/(1-a^2))$?  Do you just want $d/(1-a)$ as the conditional mean of $X$ given $a$, $d$, and $q$?

Comment: Hi @JimB, I have hopefully clarified the meaning of this in the first line now. Does this make sense?

Comment: That clarifies it.  (I just hadn't seen that notation before.)  But aren't you asking for trouble because some values of $a$ give negative variances if $a$ has a normal distribution?  Wouldn't you want a prior for $a$ to be bounded by 0 and 1?

Comment: @JimB you are completely right. I actually have a truncated norrmal prior on (a,d) which is truncated at 0 and 1 for a.

Comment: Just having a quick look at it, you'd get some terms in the integral like $exp(-ad), exp(-a^3)$. Pretty sure it wouldn't be gaussian.